# AS3 Flash/Animate - Visual Graphs - data from XML or Excell

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I've used Flash for many years as a design platform. AS3 wise, I'm a beginner of about 10 years. I've designed various graphs in flash intended to be printed and filled out by hand. However, typically I complete the graphs by drawing in the data points and lines directly in Flash. Ignoring the fact that I'm using flash for a really ridiculous purpose, is it possible to plot the data point symbols, and linking lines using `XML` or even `Excel`?

I have used `XML` to load external image files previously.

Not looking for an easy fix, but if anyone could point me in the right direction please get in touch.

Best regards,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

1. Forget Excel.
2. It is not that difficult with XML, actually. Just a quick example.

> ```
> var X:XML =
>     <root>
>         <point x="0" y="0" />
>         <point x="100" y="100" />
>         <point x="10" y="50" />
>         <point x="200" y="10" />
>         <point x="45" y="45" />
>         <point x="35" y="100" />
>     </root>;
> ```

This is pretty basic thing but it shows how to browse through the list of XML nodes and how to access their attributes.

```
drawZigzag(X);

function drawZigzag(source:XML):void
{
    // Get a list of points.
    var aList:XMLList = source.child("point");

    // Get the starting point.
    var aNode:XML = aList[0];
    var anX:Number = aNode.@x;
    var anY:Number = aNode.@y;

    // Start drawing.
    graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x000000);
    graphics.moveTo(anX, anY);

    for (var i:int = 1; i < aList.length(); i++)
    {
        // Get the next coordinates.
        aNode = aList[i];
        anX = aNode.@x;
        anY = aNode.@y;

        // Draw the line.
        graphics.lineTo(anX, anY);
    }
}
```

Now, if you want it to be an external file. This is also pretty basic, without error handling and stuff, but should work if you prepare all the thing right.

```
// I hope the following is self-explanatory.
var xmlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("your.xml");
var dataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

// Loading is asynchronous so you need to listen for a relevant event.
dataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFile);
dataLoader.load(xmlRequest);

function onFile(e:Event):void
{
    // Of course, your file MUST be a valid XML.
    var X:XML = new XML(dataLoader.data);

    // The data are ready, you can call the drawing routine now.
    drawZigzag(X);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Organis, this is great. Will take me a while to get to grips with it. All the best